# Do I always connect all GNDs together between devices?

Tags: ground, grounding

I'm trying to interface with an RS232 port on a home automation system.  The RS232 port only has RX, TX, and GND pins connected (according to the documentation).

If I'm interfacing with an Arduino (and an RS232 to TTL converter), do I connect the RS232 GND with my Arduino GND and all the other GNDs?

Comment: For safety, connect the Grounds by default. If you get hum in audio, or hum-bars in video, at least you will be safe while diagnosing. I've done high-resolution high-speed telemetry systems, where the sensors were floating above the aircraft chassis (e.g. not grounded), but experiences-of-others (not me) showed that was both safe and necessary to reduce the digital noise using that (sensor-to-chassis) path.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Current needs a return path. There are a few cases in which you should not connect grounds between devices, but in most instances, all devices need a common ground to communicate.